Appropriate way to consume Gnip Streaming Data
I am trying to consume Twitter/Gnip Stream data using the end point:
https://gnip-stream.twitter.com/stream/powertrack/accounts...

Here is the code:
with s.get(url,headers=headers, auth=auth, timeout=60, stream=True )as req:
 for line in req.iter_lines():
     count +=1
    
print(count)

The issue is that I keep getting different values for Count, most of them are off by +- 5 for the same time frame.
Is there a better way for consuming streaming data that would give me accurate/exact results ?
Thanks
